# Build Cryptomator from source github

Tags: java, windows, native

https://github.com/cryptomator/cryptomator

I've installed jdk and jre and maven3, but I don't know what do to with that:
- JCE unlimited strength policy files (needed for 256-bit keys)
- Optional: OS-dependent build tools for native packaging (see Windows, OS X, Linux)

I want to build for windows. I tried to do that witout doing something with jce and OS-dependent build tools:

```
cd main
mvn clean install -Prelease
```

Everything is successfull but I do not get a .exe like when I install it with the prebuilt version from the cryptomator website. I would need a detailed tutorial, since I'm not so familiar with java.

Comment: Well, unless you use the OS-dependent build tools from one of the additional repos you won't get any native packing.

Comment: yeah, how can I use this? I'm not familiar with java

Comment: I guess youre trying to build the windows-version, since you tagged the question with windows. The repo contains amongst other things a `pom.xml`-file, which means it can be built just like the main-project using maven.

Comment: yes for windows, can you please explain in detail, maybe formulate a answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not wan't to do something with JCE and OS-dependent build tools you will on the one hand not be able to build an exe file (because you need a tool specific to the exe format in this case) and on the other hand will not be able to run Cryptomator at all. Encryption with Java and 256bit keys requires the JCE unlimited strength policy files so these must be installed in your JDK.

To build the .exe file available from the website you will have to build the https://github.com/cryptomator/cryptomator-win respository instead. In addition when building https://github.com/cryptomator/cryptomator you will only build the UI part. The crypto code has been extracted into separate projects.

## How to do a complete build

and if you want to build the exe file completely locally you will have to build

- https://github.com/cryptomator/siv-mode,
- https://github.com/cryptomator/cryptolib,
- https://github.com/cryptomator/cryptofs,
- https://github.com/cryptomator/webdav-nio-adapter,
- https://github.com/cryptomator/cryptomator and
- https://github.com/cryptomator/cryptomator-win.

by hand.

To ensure that the correct jar files (the ones you build yourself) and not the current release versions from the [maven central repository](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.cryptomator%22) are used you will have to align the dependencies in the pom.xml files correctly. To do this use the current SNAPSHOT versions of the cryptomator projects in all places.

The module dependency tree is (which can be seen in the corresponding pom.xml files):

```
cryptomator-win
\- cryptomator
   |- cryptofs
   |  \- cryptolib
   |     \- siv-mode
   \- webdav-nio-adapter
```

Another thing to add is that Cryptomator uses a small amount of native, os-specific code. This code is contained in the https://github.com/cryptomator/native-functions repo but not build using maven. If you want to even build this part by yourself you will have to build https://github.com/cryptomator/native-functions/tree/develop/WinFunctions and replace the corresponding [.dll files in the cryptomator-win project](https://github.com/cryptomator/cryptomator-win/tree/master/package/windows).